# WordPress "Query post" doesn't load ACF gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made a page with some articles and a gallery. Everything is displayed perfectly, but I'd like to load some special article, so I use this code:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("category_name=actualites&paged=$paged;");     
?>
```

But in the end, the gallery doesn't show...
How could I display special articles, AND display the gallery which is in the loop? (I copy the code of my gallery)

```
<!-- beginning of the gallery -->
<div id="gallerie">
    <?php ;?>
    <?php $images = get_field('image_gallery');?>
    <?php if( $images ): ?>
        <div class="image-home">
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </a>                               
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<!-- end of the gallery  -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `wp_reset_query();` after your first block of code. This resets the query back to its original. Without doing so the code in your second block will fail.

It's also worth noting that `query_posts()` isn't meant to be used in plugins or themes. Read more about that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

A better way of displaying only one category would be like so:

```
function my_custom_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_page( '{name}' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '{number}' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_page' );
```